# Does k cross validation work well with Random Forest Model in R?

Tags: r

I want to build Random forest model in R and I want first to divide my dataset to Training and Testing.

all the tutorials so far use regular sampling. 
For example: training<-data[1:150,] and
testing<- data[151:700,]

I tried to use 10 cross validation with my random forest model and I want to ensure I am doing the right thing
here's my code in R

```
#the head of the dataset after deleting ID attribute
head(wpdc)

#k fold cross validation
RF_folds<-createFolds(wpdc$outcome, k=10) #create folds 
RF_fun <- lapply (RF_folds, function(x){
  RF_traing_folds=wpdc[-x,]
  RF_test_folds=wpdc[x,]
  RF_test_folds_class<-RF_test_folds[,1]
  #build the model 
  RF_model<-randomForest(outcome ~ ., data = RF_traing_folds)
  #test the  model
  RF_predict<-predict(RF_model, RF_test_folds[-1])
  #accuracy
  RF_table<-table(RF_test_folds_class,RF_predict)
  RF_confusionMatrix<-confusionMatrix(RF_table, positive ="R") #to see the matrex of echo floods
  return(RF_confusionMatrix$table)
})

RF_sum_matrices <-Reduce('+', RF_fun)/10 #sum 10 matrices
RF_final_confusionMatrix<-confusionMatrix(RF_sum_matrices, positive ="R")
RF_final_confusionMatrix
```

I read an article that says out of bag in RFs are similar to k cross validation and there's no need to use k cross validation. So my question is, is my code correct ? and is k cross validation a good choice to partition data before building a model? if so, what is the correct way to do so?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're assigning more data to your test set than your train? I'd argue (and is usually the case) that you should assign the majority of your data points to you training set. As reference, I normally split my data 70:30 train:test. 

The CV code looks OK but I can't see where you're averaging the error over the folds? I may be missing something.

Comment: @Sam where did you see that my code splits more data in Testing than training?

Comment: The second: `For example: training<-data[1:150,] and testing<- data[151:700,]` I know you said for example, but just giving pointers.